# How can I use calc to set things properly with dynamic heights?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I essentially want the first block to take up whatever height it will naturally. Then I want the second block fill out the rest of the page with its natural height, without letting it create a vertical scrollbar.

I'm basically hard-coding the *100px* via the template row. How can I make things more flexible? I've tried various values like `100%` instead of `100px` in the rows, as well as `auto`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.rest {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h2>Some text that can change length/height</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="rest">I want this block to be the remaining 100% height</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a working snippet in your questions. also, unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @DogukanCavus I never used that feature before! kukkuz was kind enough to edit question before I saw this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fr` won't work here as the height of the `container` is *auto* as you are not setting a *fixed* height to it. So you can set the height of the `container` to *100vh* (note I have set `margin` of `body` to zero to *override* the default browser margin).

Also Use `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr` to let the first row take *auto* height and the second row the *remaining* height. See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container>div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h2>Some text that can change length/height</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="rest">I want this block to be the remaining 100% height</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marked this as answer, but technically I needed one more thing. `.rest { max-height: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with flex-box.

Checkout this snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  background-color: steelblue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child-1 {
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 100%;
}

.child-2 {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child-1">
     <p>dsadsa</p>
     <p>dsadsa</p>
     <p>dsadsa</p>
     <p>dsadsa</p>
     <p>dsadsa</p>
  </div>
   <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. When I go to full screen and shrink the browser window, a scrollbar appears.

Comment: @DaveStein I edited the code and added a `height: 100vh` to the ***parent*** div, plus a global reset. It should be fine now